# "No codeFrame could be generated" error on fresh 'npm init gatsby' site

Tags: firefox, browser, gatsby

I created a fresh gatsby site by using the command `npm init gatsby` on a M1 Mac. I kept all options to default in the wizard and started by `npm run develop`. I immediately get this error on every refresh:

[image]

Although it's annoying the site is working fine. The error doesn't give much information and I couldn't find anyhting on google. My node version is **v17.2.0** and this is the auto generated package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-gatsby-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "My Gatsby Site",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem, no error anymore:

> I worked around the issue by disabling the "Delete cookies and site
> data when Firefox Developer Edition is closed" option

**Source:** https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16076#issuecomment-536152468

Answer (score 3):

There's a lack of details despite being a starter command (browser, browser version, etc). I'd try to follow one of the suggestions of this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16076):

- If you are registering a service worker, try commenting/removing it
- If not, play around with the browser cookies (allowing or disallowing):

  [image]
  Allowing the `localhost:8000` cookies.

  In the same way, using the opposite cookie approach, you can disable the "Delete cookies and site data when Firefox Developer Edition is closed" option.